# About AWS RDS pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a question

I have a RDS : db.t2.micro with storage :20GB

It's now free tier usage. I want to know when the free period is over .

Is it priced by per hour??

I find this picture (http://aws.amazon.com/rds/previous-generation/?nc2=h_ls) is use hour to count the price .

will the storage(20GB) influence my bill?? Here didn't have info about `db.t2.micro`

I want to know this to decide whether I have to delete this RDS and open a new one just 5GB

Please guide me thanks!!

[image]

Comment: I think this question is kinda Off Topic on Stackoverflow

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pricing of web services, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be charged for storage. I believe the free period is good for one year, but that doesn't apply if you created your AWS account before 2010.